# In soapUI, how do I transfer multiple property values from a groovy script to a property list, containing properties?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm getting myself acquainted with groovy (,for soapUI) and have hit a roadblock trying to figure out how to transfer some property values to a property list. Tried out property transfer steps, but didn't help. I've kinda figured out that I'd need to use *'setPropertyValue'* and *'context.expand'* to start with. Just can't connect the dots yet.

```
def myTestCase = context.testCase

File tempFile_first = new File("C:/Users/ethomas1/Desktop/my_Input_File_first.txt"
List lines_first = tempFile_first.readLines()

File tempFile_second = new File("C:/Users/ethomas1/Desktop/my_Input_File_Second.txt")
List lines_second = tempFile_second.readLines()

def x = Math.random()*10       // multiplying random with 10 so the resulting value would be <= 10.
i = String.valueOf(x).getAt(0)
i = i.toInteger()

myTestCase.setPropertyValue("num1", lines_first[i])
myTestCase.setPropertyValue("num3", lines_first[i])
myTestCase.setPropertyValue("num2", lines_second[i])
myTestCase.setPropertyValue("num4", lines_second[i])

num1 = context.expand( '${#TestCase#num1}' )
num2 = context.expand( '${#TestCase#num2}' )
num3 = context.expand( '${#TestCase#num3}' )
num4 = context.expand( '${#TestCase#num4}' )

log.info ("num1 is " + num1 + ", num2 is " + num2 + ", num3 is " + num3 + ", num4 is " + num4)
```

Comment: Well, effectively, all I need to know is how do you transfer a value from a groovy script to a property in a property list, while executing a testcase? Any help, maybe a link, or an example would greatly help.

Comment: Okay, long story, cut short.... this is what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .properties file to pull all the properties together at any level or otherwise you have to write groovy as you are writing above.
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("PropName","Value");